# Datetime nullable field store 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in nullable field,

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I am using Laravel 5.6.12 and MySQL

**Schema Migration code**

```
Schema::create('mytable', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedMediumInteger('ID')->autoIncrement();
    $table->datetime("Start_Date");
    $table->datetime("End_Date")->nullable()->default(null);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Insert Script**

```
$MyModel = new MyModel();
$MyModel->Start_Date = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
$MyModel->End_Date = null;
$MyModel->save();
```

I also get 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in the database for the End_Date field. I am expecting it to store null instead of 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Please suggest

Comment: Please check if there are any default constraints defined for that table, which might insert that info

Comment: Use something like debugbar and check which query is actually generated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is for sure. By default, the datetime enters 0000-00-00 00:00:00 as this is the default value for the datetime fields. One thing you could try is removing the ‘default->(null)’ from your migration.
And just to make sure that everything works, first try the controller as it is with no changes. If that fails, try:
    $MyModel->End_Date = ‘0’; 
to see if that works.

And finally, make sure you have all the fields mentioned as $fillable = [] in your model.

Hope this helps :)